# A default binder has been requested, but there are no binders available for 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.DirectWithAttributesChannel'

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to create the simplest as possible hello world with Spring Cloud + Kafka Streams + Spring Boot 2.

I realize I miss basic concepts. Basically, I understand that:

1 - I need to define an outbound stream to write messages to a Kafka topic, and an inbound stream to read messages from a Kafka topic

```
public interface LoansStreams {

    String INPUT = "loans-in";
    String OUTPUT = "loans-out";

    @Input(INPUT)
    SubscribableChannel inboundLoans();

    @Output(OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel outboundLoans();

}
```

2 - configure Spring Cloud Stream to bind to my streams

```
@EnableBinding(LoansStreams.class)
public class StreamsConfig {
}
```

3 - configure Kafka properties

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
      bindings:
        loans-in:
          destination: loans
          contentType: application/json
        loans-out:
          destination: loans
          contentType: application/json
```

4 - create model for exchange messages

```
@Getter @Setter @ToString @Builder
public class Loans {
    private long timestamp;
    private String result;
}
```

5 - write to Kafka

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class LoansService {
    private final LoansStreams loansStreams;
    public LoansService(LoansStreams loansStreams) {
        this.loansStreams = loansStreams;
    }
    public void sendLoan(final Loans loans) {
        log.info("Sending loans {}", loans);
        MessageChannel messageChannel = loansStreams.outboundLoans();
        messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(loans)
                .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .build());
    }
}
```

6 - listen to Kafka topic

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class LoansListener {

    @StreamListener(LoansStreams.INPUT)
    public void handleLoans(@Payload Loans loans) {
        log.info("Received results: {}", loans);

    }
}
```

I spent a whole day reading few blogs and I assume that the above code is at least workable. I amo not sure I realy coding the best aproach as possible. By the way, I get the error mentioned in the topic:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-04-26 18:33:05.619 ERROR 14784 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: A default binder has been requested, but there are no binders available for 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.DirectWithAttributesChannel' : , and no default binder has been set.
```

Googling for solution, I found someone saying to code StreamListe returning the model so I replaced it with:

```
@StreamListener(LoansStreams.INPUT)
@SendTo("loans-out")
public KStream<?, Loans> process(KStream<?, Loans> l) {
    log.info("Received: {}", l);
    return l;
}
```

and then I get an error even less clear at least to me (previous error clearly mentioned some binder issue):

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-04-26 19:01:06.016 ERROR 13276 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method must be declarative
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:118) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KafkaStreamsStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.validateStreamListenerMethod(KafkaStreamsStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.java:510) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.streams.KafkaStreamsStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.orchestrateStreamListenerSetupMethod(KafkaStreamsStreamListenerSetupMethodOrchestrator.java:168) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.doPostProcess(StreamListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:226) ~[spring-cloud-stream-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
```

In case it helps somehow, I want to evoluate this idea to apply SAGAS but it is not the focus of this question. Firstly, I need get the basic up and running.

*edited

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mybank</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kafka-cloud-stream</name>
    <description>Spring Cloud Stream With Kafka</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <!-- version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version-->
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You don't need to include `KStream` with your `StreamListener` since you don't have any `KStream` bindings. What binder you include in your build configuration? (maven/gradle etc.) How you include them? Can we see a sample config? Your steps 1 - 6 should work, might be missing something. A small sample app will help.

Comment: Yes, your interface is for the message channel binder, not the KStream binder. It's also a bit odd to read and write from/to the same topic in an app. You'll get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

"A default binder has been requested, but there are no binders available ...", please add dependency as below.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I have already spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams in my pom. I will add my whole pom above

Comment: Please notice spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka instead of spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-**streams**

Comment: And you could add both of them, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka is for kafka client api; while spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams is for kafka stream api.

Comment: Probably a very naive question, can you exemplify the difference between ...binder-kafka and ...binder-kafka-streams? I mean when I use one instread of another? I assume that ..binder-kafka-stream would offer all I get from binder-kafka plus streams feature.

Comment: @jimC - you use ..binder-kafka-streams only when your application is a Kafka Streams based application. By that I mean, you are using the kafka streams library in your application and make use of either high level DSL or low level processor API provided by kafka streams. You use ..binder-kafka when you want to leverage on Spring Integration, Spring Cloud Function/Project Reactor based constructs. They both are very different binders under the hood.

Comment: I am still confused about when use one in favour of another. I am googling around without success. If you can write just one phrase when use one in favour of another it will be usefull. PS. I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829362/what-is-the-difference-between-kafka-streams-dsl-to-processor-api bujt it doesn´t answer. In my case, I want to use Kafka to apply Daga pattern. In few words, imagine I have two microservices,  LOAN and BANK-STATEMENTand I use SAGA pattern. I am bit confident that using kafka-streams be very usefull in that scenario.

Comment: A short hint. Kakfa client is use to producer(Source) and consumer(Sink), transform(INPUT->OUTPUT), process(INPUT->OUTPUT) and bind to message channel, you can use Rabbit binder instead. And Kafka stream is advanced alternative for application process - join, branch, filter, map value and so forth. And bind to kafka topic directly.

Comment: Something worked here, thanks! Got java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer.

Answer (score 8):

You can define your default binder in application.yml (or application.properties)

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        ...
      default-binder: kafka
```

Comment: This case worked for me, because I have had two binders at the same context.

Comment: You can also use like this 'defaultBinder: kafka'

Answer (score 3):

For me, with different `application.properties` for different contexts and multiple output bindings, the only way I could fix it was defining a general default binding like:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      default-binder: eventhub
      ...
```

And the rest of bindings type individually set in each input / output as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the above pom file, you need to use `binder-kafka` and not `binder-kafka-streams`

So replace

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

With

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```